# How to restrict autocomplete for the files found from PATH?

Tags: zsh, directory, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

What I would like to be able to do is to have a list of words that are allowed to be autocompleted when typing the first word in the command line.

Say, I have `PATH=/dir`, and the directory `/dir` has two files in it — `calibre`, `calc`. And I would have this list that I want, and it has one word in it — `calc`. So, when I type `ca` and press *tab*, the command expands to `calc`, and no list of possible autocompletes is shown

Comment: and if there are executables in /dir named `car` and `can` and `calculator` etc, they should also be ignored?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes. Only those that are in the list should be autocompleted